# Windroy apps not working after restarting

Tags: android, windows, windroy

I'm using the latest version of Windroy; after installing any APK apps on the system it works fine until restarting the program, then it stops working or returns a crash error.

And also the program stops responding to the mouse moves above the screen after a while.

Using Win 7 X64.

Comment: Where is the logfile? Where are some sourcecode snippets which could include the error?

Comment: no errors are shown, the APK crashes or just freezes next time i reboot the system, and after a while maybe 1 or 2 minutes when the program is idle, then the screen never detect the mouse touches over it, the screen still viewing the android system icons or opened apps but never responds to any keyboard or mouse moves.

Comment: The CMD menu returns an application failer about this line:
created named socket<name: com.android.internal.telephony> with port 6561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: You just need to clean this directory "Windroy\data\dalvik-cache" from all the files before running Windroy again.